# How do I write a shell script to install a list of applications?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, scripts

Does anyone know how to write a shell script to install a list of applications?  It's a pain to have to install each application by hand every time I set up a new system.

**Edit:**
It still asks me `Do you want to continue [Y/n]?`.  Is there a way to have the script input `y` or for it not to prompt for input?

Comment: I made a script for this. Check http://github.com/dinukasal/install you can add packages too

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I would assume the script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get update  # To get the latest package lists
apt-get install <package name> -y
#etc.
```

Just save that as something like install_my_apps.sh, change the file's properties to make it executable, and run it from the command line as root.

(**Edit:** The `-y` tells `apt-get` not to prompt you and just get on with installing)

Comment: How to make it executable?
I assume i would run it like:  `sudo ./install_my_apps.sh`

Comment: I'm not certain whether it's necessary to make it executable (I'm a Python guy; not much into BASH). But if you must, it can be made executable with `chmod +x ./install_my_apps.sh`.

Comment: Or right click on it, select "Properties". In the window that opens go to the "Permissions" tab, and check the checkbox that says "Allow executing file as a program"

Comment: I don't know why this is CW, but I edited it anyway to put the `-y` flag. 

Note: If you want to make it look clearer, you can use `--yes` or `--assume-yes` in place of `-y`.

Answer (score 25):

Well, according to your question the easiest script would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
LIST_OF_APPS="a b c d e"

aptitude update
aptitude install -y $LIST_OF_APPS
```

However you could also enter `aptitude update && aptitude install -y a b c d e`. So maybe your question is missing the crucial point here. If there are some further requirements it would be nice to explain them.

Comment: Note that apt-get would work as a drop-in replacement for aptitude here, if that is your preference. Simply replace both instances of "aptitude" with "apt-get".

Comment: Personally I would go with aptitude as it will look for / install dependencies much better than apt

Answer (score 17):

Just create a list of apps in a file, example.list, and run

```
cat example.list | xargs sudo apt-get -y install
```

Comment: this is awesome.  never knew how to feed a list of packages into apt before!

Comment: xargs feeds the piped lines into any command, by simply appending them as arguments

Answer (score 9):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -eu -o pipefail # fail on error and report it, debug all lines

sudo -n true
test $? -eq 0 || exit 1 "you should have sudo privilege to run this script"

echo installing the must-have pre-requisites
while read -r p ; do sudo apt-get install -y $p ; done < <(cat << "EOF"
    perl
    zip unzip
    exuberant-ctags
    mutt
    libxml-atom-perl
    postgresql-9.6
    libdbd-pgsql
    curl
    wget
    libwww-curl-perl
EOF
)

echo installing the nice-to-have pre-requisites
echo you have 5 seconds to proceed ...
echo or
echo hit Ctrl+C to quit
echo -e "\n"
sleep 6

sudo apt-get install -y tig
```

---

**Explanation**:

- `set -eu -o pipefail` command:

  | Command elements | Explanation |
  | --- | --- |
  | `set` | Modify how the shell environment operates |
  | `-u` | If a variable does not exist, report the error and stop (e.g., unbound variable) |
  | `-e` | Terminate whenever an error occurs (e.g., command not found) |
  | `-o pipefail` | If a sub-command fails, the entire pipeline command fails, terminating the script (e.g., command not found) |

  **If this script encounters any errors, it will fail and exit.**

  Ref: https://www.tutorialdocs.com/article/set-command-in-bash.html
- `sudo -n true` command:

  | Command elements | Explanation |
  | --- | --- |
  | `sudo` | Run as superuser |
  | `-n` | Non-interactive. Prevents `sudo` from prompting for a password. If one is required, `sudo` displays an error message and exits |
  | `true` | Builtin command that returns a successful (zero) exit status |

  **Run as a superuser and do not ask for a password. Exit status as successful.**

  Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo, https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/internal.html
- `test $? -eq 0 || exit 1 "you should have sudo privilege to run this script"` command:

  | Command elements | Explanation |
  | --- | --- |
  | `test` | Takes an expression as an argument, evaluates it as '0' (`true`) or '1' (`false`), and returns the result to the bash variable `$?` |
  | `$?` | A variable used to find the return value as the exit status of the last executed command |
  | `-eq` | equals |
  | `0` | Value result is true |
  | `||` | Logical "OR" is a Boolean operator. It can execute commands or shell functions based on the exit status of another command |
  | `exit` | Exits the shell with a status of N. If N is unspecified, it uses the exit code of the last executed command |
  | `1` | Value result is false and used here as an argument to the exit command to use as an exit code |
  | `"you should have sudo privilege to run this script"` | If the exit code is false, print this message to the terminal |

  **Test the last variable's exit code and see if it equals '0'. If not, exit with an error and print a given message to the terminal.**

  Ref: https://linuxhint.com/bash-test-command/, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html#EXSREF, https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Logical_OR, https://linuxize.com/post/bash-exit/
- `echo installing the must-have pre-requisites` command:

  | Command elements | Explanation |
  | --- | --- |
  | `echo` | Builtin command used to print information or messages to the terminal |
  | `installing the must-have pre-requisites` | Message to print to the terminal |

  **Tell the user that it is going to install some pre-requisite packages before installing the actual program.**

  Ref: https://linuxhint.com/bash_echo/
- `while read -r p ;` command:

  | Command elements | Explanation |
  | --- | --- |
  | `while` | Create a while-loop, i.e. perform a given set of commands ad infinitum as long as the given condition evaluates to true |
  | `read` | Read a line from the standard input and store it in a variable |
  | `-r` | Option passed to `read` command that avoids the backslash escapes from being interpreted |
  | `p` | Arbitrary variable for `read` to store captured input. Here it represents each package to be installed |
  | `;` | Control operator AND. Proceed to the next command and execute it regardless of the exit status of the previous command (execute even if the previous command fails) |

  **Read a given file line by line forever or until receiving a value of "false," then continue onto the proceeding command.**

  Ref: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-while-loop/, http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html,
  https://linuxhint.com/while_read_line_bash/,
  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_09
- `do sudo apt-get install -y $p ;` command:

  | Command elements | Explanation |
  | --- | --- |
  | `do` | Reserved word used to delimit the sequence of commands which follow. i.e., start |
  | `apt-get` | Tool used by the Debian APT (Advanced Package Tool) package manager |
  | `install` | A command used to install packages |
  | `-y` | Long-form is `--yes`. assume "yes" on all query prompts |
  | `$p` | Used to call the arbitrary variable `p` from `read` and use it as standard input |

  **Install the list of packages as a superuser without prompting for confirmation to install.**

  Ref: https://itsfoss.com/apt-get-linux-guide/
- `done < <(cat << "EOF" <list of packages> EOF)` command:

  | Command elements | Explanation |
  | --- | --- |
  | `done` | Reserved word used to delimit the sequence of commands which precede. i.e., stop |
  | `<` | Redirection to the standard input |
  | `cat` | Concatenate. used for viewing, creating, and appending files |
  | `<<` | Redirection that reads input from the current source until encountering a delimiter and then using those lines as the standard input for a command |
  | `EOF` | End of File delimiter |
  | `cat << EOF-EOF` | This will read, then print everything enclosed within the `EOF` block |
  | `<(list)` | Obtain the output of the list; parentheses indicate that the list will execute in a subshell environment |

  **Read the list of packages and gather them as standard input. Redirect it to the `read` command, which captures it as the `p` variable, and then sends it to the `$p` variable, which allows it to get executed by the `install` command, and when it reaches the `EOF` delimiter, redirect the output to `done` effectively ending the `while read` loop.**

  Ref: https://linuxhint.com/cat-command-bash/, https://linuxhint.com/what-is-cat-eof-bash-script/

**The following four `echo` messages are self-explanatory:**

- `echo installing the nice-to-have pre-requisites`
- `echo you have 5 seconds to proceed ...`
- `echo or`
- `echo hit Ctrl+C to quit`

**however, the next one is not.**

- `echo -e "\n"` command:

  | Command elements | Explanation |
  | --- | --- |
  | `-e` | Enable the function of backslash characters |
  | `\n` | Backslash escaped sequence for new line |

  **This command creates a newline.**
- `sleep 6` command:

  | Command elements | Explanation |
  | --- | --- |
  | `sleep` | Delay the execution of a bash script, typically for N seconds, unless using an option to indicate longer lengths of time |

  **Delay the execution of the following command for 6 seconds.**

  Ref: https://linuxhandbook.com/bash-sleep/
- `sudo apt-get install -y tig` command:

  **Install the `tig` package with the Debian `apt-get` tool while running the installation as a superuser, and do not prompt for confirmation.**

**General references**:

- https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ubash.htm
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html

Comment: wow - a full bash tutorial out of one simple answer ;o)

Answer (score 3):

I would opt for the following script: `vim install`

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update  # To get the latest package lists
apt-get install $1 -y
```

Then I should make the above script executable `chmod +x install`. Then to use it, I could type: `./install <package_name>`. Example: `./install clang`

Comment: I wanted all the programs listed in the file.  With this method, I would still have to input the name of the program as a command line argument, so there really isn't a benefit.

Comment: @jumpnett Lol, I missed the list point. I am starting to lack caffeine and it shows. Sorry for it. May update the answer.

Comment: Plus it's going to run `update` for every program to install, time-consuming. And it needs `sudo`.

Comment: this is extremely unneccessary. You might as well put `alias install='sudo apt-get install -y'` into your `.bash_aliases`