# How a Script exit when a software does not install properly?

Tags: 14.04, scripts

i got idea form the link ([How do I write an application install shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519/how-do-i-write-an-application-install-shell-script)) and started to wrtie script for installing software in ubunt automatically. But in case if the software does not install properly, I want my script should exit saying it does not install properly or at last it should give summary that which software does not install properly. How can I achive this?

Below is my script that I started to write:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -f 
for software in vim linphone linphone-common linphone-nox git dpkg-dev
do 
    apt-get install $software -y
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APT returns a non-zero value when the installation fails.
The return value of the apt is stored in the global variable `$?`
We can use that variable to detect installation failures. Eg:

```
sudo apt-get update

for software in vim linphone linphone-common linphone-nox git dpkg-dev
do 
   sudo apt-get install $software -y

   if [ $? -ne 0 ]  #If apt returns an error, do the following...
   then
       echo "ERROR($?):Failed to install $software"
       echo "Exiting installation..."
       break
   fi 
done
```

Comment: You will have to use `apt-get install -f` too