# apt install with multiple prompted arguements

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I'm trying to create a setup.sh script that includes the following

`apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

However, it prompts a yes/no during install but then also prompts to key in regions/countries/continents which have numeric responses. This will be consistent for my purposes, how can I pass in the prompt responses for this? `-y` works when everything is a yes or no question, but what about multiple prompts of mixed types?
I'd like to respond 'y',105,2, etc.

EDIT:
This is running in a hosted Jupyter Lab Cloud VM on Gradient by Paperspace. I'm running these commands from the terminal as root on 18.04, I have to install java 8 and some python packages. The VM comes preloaded with python3 but not java 8, and I want to create a setup script that doesn't need interaction from the user.

Comment: `apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y` should work fine (although note that it isn't reccomended to use `apt`/`apt-get` in scripts). AFAIK, `openjdk-*-*` packages shouldn't have any dialogs that you have to choose. What exactly is it prompting you that you need to answer `105` for? Also, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519/how-do-i-write-a-shell-script-to-install-a-list-of-applications)

Comment: What should I use instead to do installs for a setup.sh type file? And it prompts for region/country/timezone type things where it shows a list  and you have to input the number corresponding to the thing.

Comment: Um... it shouldn't ask for those things when you install stuff. Can you see if it still happens in a live CD? Perhaps you didn't configure the region, but assuming a properly configured installation of a supported version of Ubuntu, `apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y` should just work. You shouldn't need to give the region.

Comment: Its running on a cloud vm. Specifically in a cloud hosted jupyter notebook. Not sure how much control I have over it, and if I change it I'd need to change it programmatically and include it in a setup script. Also, can you expand on what I should use instead of apt-get install for a setup script?

Comment: The environment (VM and particularly Jupyter) are important! Those key facts need to be up in the Question, not buried in comments.